# how to call a static method from a trigger handler that extends a virtual class in Apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I've got a trigger handler class which extends a virtual class from [this framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework).

```
public with sharing class OrderItemTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler { }

    public override void beforeInsert() {
        handleExWorksCalculations(Trigger.New, Trigger.oldMap, true);
    }

    public static void handleExWorksCalculations(List<OrderItem> orderItemsList, Map<Id,OrderItem> oldOrderItemsMap, Boolean isInsert) { }
```

When I deploy the class to the org I get the following error:

> force-app\main\default\classes\OrderItemTriggerHandler.cls  Method
> does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> handleExWorksCalculations(List, Map<Id,SObject>, Boolean)
> from the type OrderItemTriggerHandler (69:33)

I know I missing a fundamental concept as the parameters do match the method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code

1. You need to close class at the end.

> ```
> public with sharing class OrderItemTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandlerTest1 { //Start of Class
>          ...Code will be Here
>     } //End of Class
> ```

2. Map of Trigger.oldMap will return <Id,object> and you need to cast that map in to <Id,OrderItem>

Here is the working code

```
public with sharing class OrderItemTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandlerTest1 { 

    public override void beforeInsert() {
        handleExWorksCalculations(Trigger.New,(Map<Id,OrderItem>) Trigger.oldMap, true);
    }

    public static void handleExWorksCalculations(List<OrderItem> orderItemsList, Map<Id,OrderItem> oldOrderItemsMap, Boolean isInsert) {
    }

}
```